# HttpOnly flag not working

Tags: java, javascript, http-headers, xss

I have set the `HttpOnly` flag in the response header `Set-Cookie` as follows

```
String sessionid = httpReq.getSession().getId();
httpRes.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid + ";HttpOnly");
```

But I am still able to access the cookie through `document.cookie` in the browser's console.
Is my way of setting this flag wrong?

Comment: Have you validated what's going over the wire? Which browser are you using? Can you access the cookie from Javascript within the page, or only within the console?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have checked the response headers in browser. The `Set-cookie` header is seen as `Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID = session_id; HttpOnly`. The browsers on which I have checked this are Firefox and Google Chrome. I have tried accessing the cookie only within the console. I didn't try to access it from Javascript within the page.

Comment: Console doesn't always reflect reality. You have to try access this cookie by Javascript

Comment: @hindmost I tried accessing this cookie from Javascript and I am able to do that.

Comment: @hindmost For which responses do I need to set `HttpOnly` flag. For a single page application do I need to set the `HttpOnly` flag on the single HTML file response or response of all the JavaScript files?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Servlet version 3 or above you can specify this in your web.xml as shown below:

```
  <session-config>
    <cookie-config>
      <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
  </session-config>
```

See the schema definition for more details and config options: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-common_3_0.xsd

Comment: I am not using servlet version 3 and hence using the above method to set the HttpOnly flag. But still I am able to access the cookie.